# How to use jquery to override the background-color of a disabled input field

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am trying to use jquery to set the background-color of an input field that is disabled; however, I can not override the default grey background-color:

```
if (parseFloat($('#showDispRem').val()) > parseFloat($('#showDisp').val())){
        alert("Greater than");
//      $("showDispRem").css("background-color","#ff9999"); //failed
        $("showDispRem").css("background-color","#ff9999 !important"); //failed
//      $("showDispRem").css("cssText", "background-color #ff9999 !important;"); //failed
}
```

Comment: `$("#showDispRem").css("background-color","#ff9999 !important"); //Pass`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that in your code, you forgot to add a `#` or `.` to the beginning of your selector. Therefore, JQuery is trying to find `<showDispRem>`, but not `<input id="showDispRem" />`.

Make sure to add a `#` at the front.